# How do I migrate existing Apple ID accounts automatically after federation for a domain is enabled in Apple Business Manager?

Tags: icloud, migration, apple-business

We just registered the company domain on Apple Business Manager and enabled federation.

A lot of co-workers used their work email for iCloud already and are now asked to migrate those "personal" accounts.

Clearly those accounts are not personal and the workflow to migrate those accounts is really clunky and confusing.

Is there a way to just tell Apple that those accounts should be left alone and just enable SSO on them?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of this being added since Apple will generate a new AppleID for each account that fails to self-migrate within 60 days. Plan on this being a total / on-time / no exceptions exercise now that you've exerted ownership on your domain with Apple ID services.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252362033

Since [managed Apple ID have some serious limitations for most people](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-business-manager/use-managed-apple-ids-axm78b477c81/1/web/1#axmc024e4953), they will want to make a new "personal" ID or just keep using the new assigned ID which will then free your business up to assign that "reserved" ID for work purposes.

> can’t use Apple Pay, no Find My, can’t add HomeKit devices, no purchasing from App Store, iTunes Store, Apple Books

Since you have a business relationship with Apple, you might contact your support engineer / sales team in case there are undocumented / new features that could help. My expectation is you can't undo this and your employees will all have to take action to keep using their "personal" accounts - even if it's to sign in with their old / existing password with the new assigned random email Apple will assign them shortly.